# Can libraries be included in databricks repos?

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-repos

I tried to move a cluster library into a databricks repo and I got this error message:

[image]

It seems to be not supported, but then I found this question in the documentation:
[image]

I was able to add the libraries moving the whole folder where I put them, but then they are not recognized bit git as changes.

Does anybody have an answer for this?